# concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor : KeyboardInterrupt not triggering application exit on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, threadpool, concurrent.futures

I've noticed that `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` works somewhat well on Darwin OS in cleanly exiting the application when interrupted by `KeyboardInterrupt`. However, this is not the case for Windows 10, where the process hangs for minutes without any indication of a thrown exception.

Here's an example code:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

URLS *= 100

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing a timeout kwarg or something of the like.

Comment: Searching with `python threadpoolexecutor ctrl-c site:stackoverflow.com` returns some results - do any of them answer your question?

Comment: Or search terms `threadpoolexecutor kill threads site:stackoverflow.com`,

Comment: Have you got the answer? I got the same problem in Windows 10